# java hashCode();

Tags: java, hashcode

Есть требование, что экземпляры одного и того же класса должны иметь возможность быть отсортированными по времени создания экземпляра класса. Другими словами необходимо знать  когда был создан каждый экземпляр класса А.
Насколько плохой практикой будет переопределенный метод hashCode () системное время создания  экземпляра класса,естественно приведенного к типу int?

Comment: Минус  то за что?  15 секунд после публикации и уже  минус.

Comment: Боты (с)... Если совсем просто - плохой практикой.

Comment: тогда как  узнать время создания экземпляра?

Comment: а что вам создание запрещает переопределить, завести отдельное поле под временную метку (CreatedAtTime) и заполнять прям в конструкторе? Сортировать соответственно по этому же полю :)

Comment: Как hashCode относится к времени создания?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Ну если в момент создания кидать обьект в хэштаблицу.... :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ничего не мешает. только у меня в конструкторе уже больше  20  параметров. Ну  видимо  придется  делать  по  вашему совету

Comment: Станет больше 21, это проблема? если проблема - делайте декомпозицию класса :)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, там  ситуация другая есть  классы  которые  создаются  и  работают  неделями,  результатом работы класса есть запись  в базу данных.  Поскольку  деструкторов  у меня то     выбирая   класс по  метке создания то другие кассы не запускать.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, не знаю,  Ваше  решение на ходу ,  видимо другого я  не придумаю.просто  думал  раз hashCode  это нативный вызов, то  он будет лучше  что  ли...

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть [контракт](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#:%7E:text=The%20general%20contract%20of%20hashCode,on%20the%20object%20is%20modified.) метода `hashCode()` :

1. Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
2. If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
3. It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

То видно, что такой способ создания хэш-кода нарушает 2 принцип: у вас может быть 2 созданных в разное время объекта, идентичных через `equals()`, но их хэшкоды будут разными (по определению).

Как предлагали выше, можно сделать новое поле объекта `createdAtTime` и сравнивать объекты по этому полю (например, реализовав интерфейс `Comparable`).

Comment: Да  спасибо, Я  уже  напоролся  у меня в микросекудну  создаются три-четыре объекта.   Те. у всех  одинаковый номер.. Просто не подумал что так  быстро они могут  создаваться